# 20 cards facing down

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are $20$ cards facing down. We call a **move** turning a **face down card up** and the **turning the card to its immediate right**. Prove that this sequence of moves must terminate.

**My approach:**

> Treating face down cards as 1. We will soon reach a stage where cards
>   will be like $00101101.....1$
>
> If we shuffle $11$ we get $00$
>
> If we shuffle $10$ we get $01$
>
> i.e. a decreasing binary number.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What have you tried?  The usual approach is to find some quantity that decreases with every move.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Alternative proof: the leftmost card can only be turned at most once.  This will give a proof by induction on the number of cards.